# Layouts using hbox and vbox in sencha touch

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch. i need a layout that icons should be arranged horizontally. i tried with three icons but only the first icons is showing. other icons are hiding behind. can any one pls help me in fixing the errors

here is my code:

```
 {                      
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout:'vbox',
    width:'300',
    height:'600',
    align:'center',
    items:[
    {
     xtype:'image',
     left:'40%',
     'http://myimage.com/image.png'
      style: 'background-color: #fff'
    },
    {
     xtype:'image',
     right:'40%',
     'http://myimage.com/image.png'
     style:'background-color: #fff'
    },                   
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `hbox` with `flex` and for image component `url` should be given to `src` config.

```
    {                      
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout:'hbox',
        align:'center',
        defaults: {
            flex : 1
        },
        items:[
           {
              xtype:'image',
              src:'http://myimage.com/image.png',
              style: 'background-color: #fff;'
           },
           {
              xtype:'image',
              src:'http://myimage.com/image.png',
              style:'background-color: #fff'
            }                   
         ]
   }
```

**Update**

```
    {                      
       xtype: 'panel',
       layout:'hbox',
       defaults: {
          flex : 1
       },
        items:[
           {
              xtype:'panel',
              html:'<img width="100%" src="http://myimage.com/image.png">',
              style: 'background-color: #fff;'
            },
            {
              xtype:'panel',
              html:'<img width="100%" src="http://myimage.com/image.png">',
              style:'background-color: #fff'
            }                   
          ]
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply.. am getting the image but it is overlapping behind each other in the mobile view. can you pls tell me how to overcome this issue

Comment: @user2790089 it's because of image size i think.. see my update

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create an Ext.List with the [inline](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-inline) config enabled:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.List', {
        fullscreen: true,
        inline: true,
        itemTpl: '<img src="{img}" />',
        data: [
            {img: 'http://myimage.com/image1.png'},
            {img: 'http://myimage.com/image2.png'},
            {img: 'http://myimage.com/image3.png'}
        ]
    });
```

Hope it helps-